# Iterator loop with array

Tags: java, foreach

I just have what I'm sure is a very easy and quick question here... So let's say I have an Account class as follows:

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class Account
{
    private final double RATE = 0.03; // interest rate of 3.5%
    private long acctNumber;
    private double balance;
    private String name;

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    // Sets up the account by defining its owner, account number,
    // and initial balance.
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    public Account (String owner, long account, double initial)
    {
        name = owner;
        acctNumber = account;
        balance = initial;
    }
    //----------------------------------------------------------------- 
    // Deposits the specified amount into the account. Returns the
    // new balance.
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    public double deposit (double amount)
    {
        balance = balance + amount;
        return balance;
    }
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    // Withdraws the specified amount from the account and applies
    // the fee. Returns the new balance.
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    public double withdraw (double amount, double fee)
    {
        balance = balance - amount - fee;
        return balance;
    }
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    // Adds interest to the account and returns the new balance.
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    public double addInterest ()
    {
        balance += (balance * RATE);
        return balance;
    }
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    // Returns the current balance of the account.
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    public double getBalance ()
    {
        return balance;
    }
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    // Returns a one-line description of the account as a string.
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    public String toString ()
    {
        NumberFormat fmt = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
        return acctNumber + "\t" + name + "\t" + fmt.format(balance);
    }
}
```

And I create the Bank class shown here...

```
public class Bank 
{   
    Account[] accounts;// = new Account[30];
    int count=0;
    String name;

    public Bank(String name)
    {
        this.name = name; 
        accounts = new Account[30];
    }
    public void addAccount(Account acct)
    {
        accounts[count] = acct;
        count++;
    }
    public void addInterest()
    {
        //for (Account acct : accounts)
            //acct.addInterest();
        for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            accounts[i].addInterest();
    }
}
```

I receive an error if I try to use the addInterest() method with the 
for (Account acct: accounts) loop you see commented out. Can someone please provide me with insight on why this is? I thought these loops were equivalent. Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you ever call addAccount()?  With the code you show, you've declared the account array but you haven't actually instantiated any Account objects.  If this is the error, you'll be getting a NulPointerExxception....

Comment: As a general comment, you should avoid arrays like the plague. Use [`Collections`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) (in this case a [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) seems appropriate), which among many other great features, grow in size automatically when you `.add()` things to them.

Comment: @atk No you wouldn't get an exception - the loop would just iterate zero times - no error

Comment: @Bohemian: I just went back and ran a quick test with an area of 30 null string objects.  The loop will occur 30 times if not otherwise interrupted.  The method call against the null instance will result in a null pointer exception

Comment: I think you had the right idea atk. I assumed the loop would only execute for as many accounts as I had added, but instead it seems it tries to execute 30 times. So it appears the null instances were causing the error. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The for loop over an iterable array iterates all 30 elements, not only the elements you really added.

You may use an `ArrayList<Account>` and add elements as needed. This allows you to omit the count field:

```
public class Bank 
{   
    ArrayList<Account> accounts = new ArrayList<Account>();
    String name;

    public Bank(String name)
    {
        this.name = name; 
    }
    public void addAccount(Account acct)
    {
        accounts.add(acct);
    }
    public void addInterest()
    {
        for (Account acct : accounts)
            acct.addInterest();
    }
}
```

Comment: This was much neat answer :-)

Comment: Thanks. I was calling the addInterest() method after having added only three accounts, so I think you hit the nail on the head. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize the Account array

so you might want to change this to:

```
public void addInterest()
    {
        //for (Account acct : accounts)
            //acct.addInterest();
        for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            accounts[i].addInterest();
    }
```

to something like this:

```
     public void addInterest()
        {
            for (Account acct : accounts)    {
            acct= new Account("John",1234596069,200.00);
            acct.addInterest();
            }
//            for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
//                accounts[i].addInterest();
        }
```

Essentially you have to initialize the array variable before invoking a method.

Comment: Thanks. I had a main method where I instantiated a bank object and added some accounts, but I realize I didn't show that here. Appreciate you taking the time to look over my code.